Htaccess for subdirs with language suffix to a new domain
I could do with some help please.
I have a current website: www.currentsite.com
It has urls structures for a set of products (sea, snow, swim, etc) e.g. www.currentsite.com/sea-en/ and sub products www.currentsite.com/Sea-en/surf etc
It has five languages www.currentsite.com/Sea-de/ (-en, -fr, -nl etc)
I want to be able to redirect all these products and sub products to the following bit without the language suffixes.
So like this redirect www.currentsite.com/Sea-de/ to www.newsite/sea/ for all languages and also
redirect all the sub products www.currentsite.com/Sea-de/surf to www.newsite/sea/products/surf
Is this possible and if so can anyone help me please?

Are currentsite.com and newsite.com pointing to different servers? You've used both /sea-en/ and /Sea-en/ in your example - is this just a typo and it's lowercase throughout (redirecting like-for-like) - as you don't explicitly mention this case difference in your question - or do you need to lowercase this product name as part of the redirect?

Assuming currentsite.com and newsite.com are pointing to different servers, then you could do it like this using mod_rewrite at the top of your root .htaccess file at currentsite.com:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)-(en|de|fr|nl|xx)/?$ https://www.newsite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)-(?:en|de|fr|nl|xx)/([\w-]+)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1/products/$2 [R=301,L]

This maintains the case of the original source URL. eg. /Sea-en redirects to /Sea/ and /sea-en/ redirects to /sea/.
Additional notes:

xx is the 5th language code, not specified in your question. Although you could change the last part of the regex that matches the language code from (en|de|fr|nl|xx) to [a-z]{2} to match any 2 lowercase character language code, providing this does not conflict with your existing URLs.
The trailing slash is optional on the source (non-product) URL but enforced on the target. The sub-product URL is assumed to never have a trailing slash (as per your example).
The product and sub-product names can consist of 1 or more characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore) and - (hyphen).
$1 and $2 are backreferences to the captured subpatterns in the preceding regex. ie. The "product" and "sub-product" names respectively. Note in the 2nd rule, the language code is a non-capturing group (that starts (?:) so as to not affect the backreference numbering.


Hello Mr White, thanks for your prompt help with that. I will be trying it next week. Regards Guy
